# Register Embed Handler for Padlet.com

Tags: oembed, regex

I'm trying and failing to register an embed code for content from padlet.com (strangely it's supported in WP.com but not WP.org). A URL like

```
 https://padlet.com/cogdogblog/aos9fosbbwk4
```

should embed like

```html
<div class="padlet-embed" style="border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:2px;box-sizing:border-box;overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:100%;background:#F4F4F4"><p style="padding:0;margin:0"><iframe src="https://padlet.com/embed/aos9fosbbwk4" frameborder="0" allow="camera;microphone;geolocation" style="width:100%;height:608px;display:block;padding:0;margin:0"></iframe></p>
```

My attempt that fails so far

```php
add_action( 'init', function(){
  $regex_url = '#https?://padlet\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$#i';

  wp_embed_register_handler(
    'padlet',
    $regex_url,
    'wp_embed_handler_padlet',
    true
  );
});


function wp_embed_handler_padlet( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr )
{
  $embed = sprintf(
    '<div class="padlet-embed" style="border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:2px;box-sizing:border-box;overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:100%;background:#F4F4F4"><p style="padding:0;margin:0"><iframe src="https://padlet.com/embed/%1$s" frameborder="0" allow="camera;microphone;geolocation" style="width:100%;height:608px;display:block;padding:0;margin:0"></iframe></p>',
    esc_attr($matches[2])
    );

  return apply_filters( 'embed_padlet', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
}
```

I am sure it is my regex clumsiness. It would sure help newbies like me if the [Codex docs for this function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler) had a better explained (and actually working) example.

And what form of regex is used in `wp_embed_register_handler`? None of the online testers I use have this format and requires escaping of `/` - looking for a place to test patterns that WordPress uses.

**UPDATE**
After failing to find Padlet listed as an oembed provider https://oembed.com/ and not finding any documentation on their developer site https://padlet.readme.io/ I decided to wild guess at the URL for an oembed request from the format

```
 https://padlet.com/oembed?url=https%3A//padlet.com/XXXXXX/yyyyyyyyyy&format=json
```

or a real example

https://padlet.com/oembed?url=https%3A//padlet.com/cogdogblog/aos9fosbbwk4&format=json

And I get a response (this makes sense as this is how WordPress.com is likely supporting it). So now I get full support via the much simpler:

```php
wp_oembed_add_provider( "https://padlet.com/*", "https://padlet.com/oembed/", false );
```

Comment: The escaping is due to the regex needing to go inside a PHP string literal, it isn't a part of the regex itself

Comment: You could always ask for the padlet oembed code from wp.com support

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a simpler regex such as:

```php
'#^https?://padlet\.com/(\?.+)?$#'
```

Then breaking apart the latter section with `explode` to get the video ID?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the inline styles on the `<iframe>` are causing the embed to choke due to WP's sanitizing of the HTML. I was able to get the embed to work once I removed the inline styles and balanced the HTML tags:

```php
    add_action( 'init', function(){
        $regex_url = '#https?://padlet\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$#i';

        wp_embed_register_handler(
                'padlet',
                $regex_url,
                'wp_embed_handler_padlet',
                true
        );
    });


    function wp_embed_handler_padlet( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr ) {
        $embed = sprintf(
            '<div class="padlet-embed">
                <iframe src="//padlet.com/embed/%1$s" frameborder="0" allow="camera;microphone;geolocation"></iframe>
            </div>',
            esc_attr($matches[2])
        );

        return apply_filters( 'embed_padlet', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
    }
```

[image: padlet embed example]

You can style the embed by targeting `.padlet-embed` in your CSS rather than adding the styles inline.

Edit: Tested in the block editor and it works on both the backend and frontend without any changes but you need to use the embed block.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This makes sense. I am planning to run as a plugin for a few embeds, and can enqueue a style sheet. However, I copied your code exactly, and am still getting a failed embed. Will go over again.

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by "failed embed"? If you inspect the HTML, what do you see? If you debug `$matches` in `wp_embed_handler_padlet` e.g.  `error_log( print_r( $matches, true ) );` what do you see? I was thinking it could be an oembed [caching issue](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/embed-2/cache/clear/), but after investigating, it looks like only native oembeds are cached.

Comment: Ah, never mind. I was getting the fail in the block editor paragraph block, it works in the classic block. I guess I need to figure out how to add support or maybe write a block?

Comment: Can you use the `embed` block? When I do that, it works for me.

Comment: Mine still fails in the embed block. Revised regex to simpler and explode on "/" suggested https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/359696/14945

Comment: See original post, I was able to find the oembed provider url (though it's not documented anywhere)